# How to change Content property in ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have custom ContentControl

```
public class MyContentControl: ContentControl
{....}
```

with Content defined in XAML like this

```
    <controls:MyContentControl x:Name="myContentControl">
        <controls:MyContentControl.Content>
            <controls:UserControl1 />
        </controls:MyContentControl.Content>
    </controls:MyContentControl>
```

Content shows in designer and in the device when I launch my application. But when I try to change Content property programmatically, for example

```
        UserControl2 control2 = new UserControl2();            
        myContentControl.Content = control2;
```

MyContentControl shows nothing. Using standard ContentControl give the same result.
Any suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The reason could be that the control does not stretch and is displayed just 0x0 in size. Try to set absolute `Width` and `Height` to the `control2` and check if it displays. You can also set `myContentControl.HorizontalContentStretch` and `myContentControl.VerticalContentStretch`.

You can try running the app in debugger and then use the Live Property Explorer to see what the actual size of the control inside `Content` is.

Answer (score 1):

I followed your code to make simple code sample to test. There's no problem.

```
public class CustomContentControl:ContentControl
{//......}
```

```
<Grid>
    <local:CustomContentControl x:Name="content">
    </local:CustomContentControl>
</Grid>
```

```cs
MyUserControl1 myUserControl1 = new MyUserControl1();
content.Content = myUserControl1;
```

```
<UserControl
x:Class="AppContent.MyUserControl1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:AppContent"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="300"
d:DesignWidth="400">

<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="abc"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

You might have done some specific settings in your code. @Martin Zikmund's suggestion also was reasonable. You could refer to his suggestion and check your code. After that, if you still could not solve this issue, please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out where the things went wrong. I am using different controls for desktop and mobile devices, so I put some of theirs XAML views to the DeviceFamily-Mobile folder. This way they automatically use when needed. I've confused namespaces, because all XAML views in this folder have a root namespace for accessibility reasons. When I was trying to add control to the ContentControl via c#, I didn't resolve namespace where my controls were placed. So I've put XAML view as a childs to the ContentControl, and they staying invisible as none of them has InitializeComponent() method. Adding correct controls with initialization fixed my problem.

I am very grateful for your answers, they pointed me to the right way.